# Using Selenium, how to run test scripts on a certain page of an application without using a login page

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am working on an application that whenever I call a page from the menu, the URL does not change. I'm new to Selenium and am creating automation test scripts to perform test cases.

But, for each test script, I have to add a script for user authentication to call the login page and call the required page from the menu.

Is there a way I can call the page directly without user authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is: no. Unless you have user authentication turned off in a dev or test (non-production) environment, you can't bypass it! This would be a security issue and could cause more bugs to occur, as you'll get used to testing software without authentication. This will create a "blinder" for you, which you don't want!

So what can you do?

1. Have your test automation always login. Create a login class/method that you can use for any test.
2. Using code, generate a user authentication token. You can pass this token in your `beforeAll()` method and have your automation library (Selenium, Cypress, Playwright, etc) use DevTools to set a cookie or session/user token.

The second option is highly dependent on what software is being tested. It can be based on language, library/framework, or even APIs being used. I recommend working with your dev team to understand what's being used. Hopefully, it's an API, which will make it a lot easier!